# imagewithcgimage always returns bad access memory error in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uikit

What I'm doing is create CGImage from bitmap data and convert it to UIImage.

I have code below

```
 - (UIImage *)imageWithBitmapBytes:(Byte *)imageBytes width:(size_t)width height:(size_t)height pixelCount:(NSUInteger)pixelCount {
    NSUInteger imageBufferSize = width * height * pixelCount;
    CGDataProviderRef dataProviderRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, imageBytes, imageBufferSize, nil);
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    NSUInteger bitsPerPixel = bitsPerComponent * pixelCount;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = width * pixelCount;
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageRetain(CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), kCGImageAlphaLast, dataProviderRef, nil, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault));
    CGDataProviderRelease(dataProviderRef);
    UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return image;
}
```

I tested this code on both condition ARC turned on and turned off.

I always get Bad access memory error on this line

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is :

```
NSUInteger imageBufferSize = width * height * pixelCount;
```

because , **imageBufferSize** should be length of **imageBytes** ...

hope it helps you